# How to achieve smooth edges for filtering with AVDepthData

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to imitate the Portrait mode Apple created in their camera app. At the moment I get a working result, but not satisfying, as the object that I am trying to filter out has the filter going on to the edges instead of having an accurate line surrounding it (images attached).

I used [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/168312/image-depth-maps-tutorial-ios-getting-started) tutorial for my implementation.
You can easily see the differences between my result and Apple's result by looking at these images.

I really just took the exact code from the tutorial that I linked to, but I will add these important snippets:

//create the mask for the filters:

```
func createMask(for depthImage: CIImage, withFocus focus: CGFloat = 0.5, andScale scale: CGFloat, andSlope slope: CGFloat = 4.0, andWidth width: CGFloat = 0.1) -> CIImage {

    let s1 = slope
    let s2 = -slope
    let filterWidth =  2 / slope + width
    let b1 = -s1 * (focus - filterWidth / 2)
    let b2 = -s2 * (focus + filterWidth / 2)

    let mask0 = depthImage
        .applyingFilter("CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
            "inputRVector": CIVector(x: s1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputGVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: s1, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputBVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: s1, w: 0),
            "inputBiasVector": CIVector(x: b1, y: b1, z: b1, w: 0)])
        .applyingFilter("CIColorClamp")

    let mask1 = depthImage
        .applyingFilter("CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
            "inputRVector": CIVector(x: s2, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputGVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: s2, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputBVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: s2, w: 0),
            "inputBiasVector": CIVector(x: b2, y: b2, z: b2, w: 0)])
        .applyingFilter("CIColorClamp")

    var combinedMask = mask0.applyingFilter("CIDarkenBlendMode", withInputParameters: ["inputBackgroundImage" : mask1])
    let mask = combinedMask.applyingFilter("CIBicubicScaleTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputScaleKey: scale])

    return mask
}
```

//apply the filter according to the mask:

```
func blur(image: CIImage, mask: CIImage, orientation: UIImageOrientation = .up, blurRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let invertedMask = mask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")

    let output = image.applyingFilter("CIMaskedVariableBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputMask" : invertedMask,
                                                                                    "inputRadius": blurRadius])

    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: image.extent) else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation)
}
```

[image: This image is my result]
[image: This is Apples camera app result]

At this point I am just trying to understand what would be my next step in improving this result. Maybe some extra work on the depth map? Maybe there is a smoother way to apply the filter according to the depth map?